# How to get absolute path for css and script

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How to get absolute path for stylesheet or javascript files.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('/css/main.css');?>
```

Is giving URL

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dev/theme/Default/css/main.css" />
```

And I am looking for

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/dev/theme/Default/css/main.css" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm really wondering why you would want to do so if the CSS files are served on the same domain as your website, but this will probably work;

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css($this->Html->url('/css/main.css', true));?>
```

HtmlHelper::url() (inherited from Helper::url() takes two arguments. The first is the path as a string or array (to make use of cakephp routing), if a Boolean 'true' is passed as its second argument, a 'full' URL is generated.

I'm not at my computer at the moment, so haven't been able to test it, but I think it should work.

**update**

I had a quick look at the source: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L431

and HtmlHelper::css() uses Helper::assetUrl() internally;

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L305

So this may work as well and if it works, it's a cleaner solution:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('main', null, array('fullBase' => true));?>
```